# how to write a query to get multilevel data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have four tables as below:

**tblAccount**

```
Id i sprimary key
```

```
+----+-----------------+
| Id |  AccName        |
+----+-----------------+
|  1 | AccountA         |
|  2 | AccountB         |
+----+-----------------+
```

**tblLocation**

```
Id is primary key.
```

```
+----+---------------+
| Id |  LocName      |
+----+---------------+
|  1 | LocationA     |
|  2 | LocationB     |
|  3 | LocationC     |
+----+---------------+
```

**tblAccountwiseLocation**

```
Id i sprimary key.LocId and AccId are foreign key.
```

```
+----+---------------+---------------+
| Id |  LocId        |  AccId        |
+----+---------------+---------------+
|  1 |   1           |    1          |
|  2 |   2           |    1          |
|  3 |   3           |    1          |
|  4 |   1           |    2          |
|  5 |   2           |    2          |
|  6 |   3           |    2          |
+----+---------------+---------------+
```

**tblRSCMaster**

```
Id i sprimary key.LocId and AccId are foreign key.
```

```
+----+---------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
| Id |  LocId        |  AccId        |  RSCNo         |  DateOfAddition  |
+----+---------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
|  1 |   1           |    1          | Acc1_Loc1_1_14 |    15/01/2014    |
|  2 |   2           |    1          | Acc1_Loc2_1_14 |    15/01/2014    |
|  3 |   3           |    1          | Acc1_Loc2_1_14 |    15/01/2014    |
|  4 |   1           |    2          | Acc2_Loc1_1_14 |    15/01/2014    |
|  5 |   2           |    2          | Acc2_Loc2_1_14 |    15/01/2014    |
|  6 |   3           |    2          | Acc2_Loc3_1_14 |    15/01/2014    |
|  7 |   1           |    1          | Acc1_Loc1_2_14 |    15/02/2014    |
|  8 |   2           |    1          | Acc1_Loc2_2_14 |    15/02/2014    |
|  9 |   3           |    1          | Acc1_Loc3_2_14 |    15/02/2014    |
| 10 |   1           |    2          | Acc2_Loc1_2_14 |    15/02/2014    |
| 11 |   2           |    2          | Acc2_Loc2_2_14 |    15/02/2014    |
| 12 |   3           |    2          | Acc2_Loc3_2_14 |    15/02/2014    |
| 13 |   1           |    1          | Acc1_Loc1_3_14 |    15/03/2014    |
| 14 |   2           |    1          | Acc1_Loc2_3_14 |    15/03/2014    |
| 15 |   3           |    1          | Acc1_Loc3_3_14 |    15/03/2014    |
| 16 |   1           |    2          | Acc2_Loc1_3_14 |    15/03/2014    |
| 17 |   2           |    2          | Acc2_Loc2_3_14 |    15/03/2014    |
| 18 |   3           |    2          | Acc2_Loc3_3_14 |    15/03/2014    |
| 19 |   1           |    1          | Acc1_Loc1_4_14 |    15/04/2014    |
| 20 |   2           |    1          | Acc1_Loc2_4_14 |    15/04/2014    |
| 21 |   3           |    1          | Acc1_Loc3_4_14 |    15/04/2014    |
| 22 |   1           |    2          | Acc2_Loc1_4_14 |    15/04/2014    |
| 23 |   2           |    2          | Acc2_Loc2_4_14 |    15/04/2014    |
| 24 |   3           |    2          | Acc2_Loc3_4_14 |    15/04/2014    |
| 25 |   1           |    1          | Acc1_Loc1_5_14 |    15/05/2014    |
| 26 |   2           |    1          | Acc1_Loc2_5_14 |    15/05/2014    |
| 27 |   3           |    1          | Acc1_Loc3_5_14 |    15/05/2014    |
| 28 |   1           |    2          | Acc2_Loc1_5_14 |    15/05/2014    |
| 29 |   2           |    2          | Acc2_Loc2_5_14 |    15/05/2014    |
| 30 |   3           |    2          | Acc2_Loc3_5_14 |    15/05/2014    |
+----+---------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
```

Acc1_Loc1_1_14 resembles RSC for LocationA of AccountA for Jan 2014.

I need to get a output as below from tblRSCMaster.

```
+---------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
|  LocId        |  AccId        |  RSCNo         |  DateOfAddition  |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
|   1           |    1          | Acc1_Loc1_3_14 |    15/03/2014    |
|   1           |    1          | Acc1_Loc1_4_14 |    15/04/2014    |
|   1           |    1          | Acc1_Loc1_5_14 |    15/05/2014    |
|   2           |    1          | Acc1_Loc2_3_14 |    15/03/2014    |
|   2           |    1          | Acc1_Loc2_4_14 |    15/04/2014    |
|   2           |    1          | Acc1_Loc2_5_14 |    15/05/2014    |
|   3           |    1          | Acc1_Loc3_3_14 |    15/03/2014    |
|   3           |    1          | Acc1_Loc3_4_14 |    15/04/2014    |
|   3           |    1          | Acc1_Loc3_5_14 |    15/05/2014    |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+------------------+
```

Each account has multiple locations and each location has multiple RSCs.

I need to get last three RSCs for each location for AccountA.

I have tried the below query:

```
   SELECT tblAccountwiseLocation.LocId,tblAccountwiseLocation.AccId,tblRSCMaster.RSCNo,tblRSCMaster.DateOfAddition FROM   tblAccountwiseLocation
   INNER JOIN tblRSCMaster ON tblAccountwiseLocation.LocId= tblRSCMaster.LocId
   where tblRSCMaster.AccId=1
```

But not getting the proper output.
Please help me out.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: Why do you need to `INNER JOIN` when you need only one table? And by the way you did tell us exactly the criteria for the records that you want retrieve?

Comment: I need last three RSCs for all Locations belongs to AccountA.thatsy inner joined the tables for getting the result.

Comment: @Edper: I have edited my question. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the existing query inside a common table expression, and use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get only the last 3 (by tblRSCMaster.DateOfAddition) entries per tblAccountwiseLocation.LocId.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT tblAccountwiseLocation.LocId,
       tblAccountwiseLocation.AccId,
       tblRSCMaster.RSCNo,
       tblRSCMaster.DateOfAddition,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY tblAccountwiseLocation.LocId
                          ORDER BY tblRSCMaster.DateOfAddition DESC) rn
  FROM   tblAccountwiseLocation
  INNER JOIN tblRSCMaster 
    ON tblAccountwiseLocation.LocId = tblRSCMaster.LocId
   AND tblAccountwiseLocation.AccId = tblRSCMaster.AccId
  WHERE tblRSCMaster.AccId=1
)
SELECT LocId, AccId, RSCNo, DateOfAddition
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY LocId, AccId, DateOfAddition
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/503b4/1).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

```
select m.*
from (select m.*, row_number() over (partition by accID
                                     order by DateOfAddition desc) as seqnum
      from tblRSCMaster
      where m.locid = 1
     ) m
where seqnum <= 3
order by AccId, DateOfAddition;
```

I think you need to filter on the `locid` rather than on the `AccId` to get what you want.